# Is updating with value using a subquery bad in performance?

Tags: performance

I have made an update query in the following form:

```
update table_a
set some_column = (
    select very_complicated_expression_involving_multiple_columns_in_table_b
    from table_b
    where table_a.id = table_b.id
)
```

If `table_a` is large, will the database engine loop the select query for each row in `table_a`? Should I rewrite this to an `update from` statement?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  Sql Server?

Comment: You haven't filtered any rows in table_a and you haven't joined table_a to any other table to reduce the number of rows that need to be read.  You have only said to update some_column on table_a with a value from your subquery.  I would think there is no alternative to reading all rows from table_a

Comment: Also, in your example: if no row exists in table_b for the id in table_a, you'll be updating table_a.some_column with null.

Comment: @ScottHodgin This is my intended behaviour. I am updating a column for the whole `table_a` according to another table. I am worried that `select` from `table_b` is executed multiple times in this case, rather than using a `join` / `update from` / something like that where `table_b` is only queried exactly once.

Comment: Are you using sql server?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? But in general: check your execution plan

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Sql Server as your DBMS:

The following two statements are **NOT** equivalent:

```
update table_a --will update some_column to null when no match to table_b on id
set some_column = (
    select very_complicated_expression_involving_multiple_columns_in_table_b
    from table_b
    where table_a.id = table_b.id
)

UPDATE a --will not update table_a rows that don't match table_b on id
SET a.some_column = very_complicated_expression_involving_multiple_columns_in_table_b
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.id
```

The first `UPDATE` will update some_column to NULL if there is no match between table_a and table_b on id.

The second `UPDATE` won't update any table_a rows where there is no match between table_a and table_b on id.

Having said that, and back to your original question about performance, I would think the optimizer would NOT choose any kind of `LOOP JOIN` when there are so many rows involved in the update (assuming your statistics are up to date).  Evaluating different estimated execution plans for different flavors of the update will help you decide which is the most efficient.

There are other things that also need to be considered when updating a large table.

- An update against a large table will generated a lot of transaction log entries.  You should *consider* breaking up the update into smaller chunks to reduce the possibility of running out of log space.  If you're running in `FULL` recovery mode, make sure you are taking log backups in a timely manner.  You would need to determine a method of identifying rows that have already been updated in previous runs.  [Break large delete operations into chunks](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes) is a post about breaking up large deletes, but I think the idea can be applied to updates.
- If `some_column` is referenced in any indexes on table_a, you should consider dropping/disabling them.  Naturally, they will have to be rebuilt afterwards.
- Check for any `UPDATE` triggers on table_a that might impact performance.